# What is that Boeing 757 custom cockpit interface?

Tags: avionics, feature-identification, boeing-757

[image]
Cropped; [flickr.com](https://www.flickr.com/photos/flyforfun/2290817109/sizes/z/), 2008

The photo is taken in cruise. The selected display shows takeoff data. There is also a send button (which hints at a datalink capability for communicating values).

I searched for performance calculators and datalink solutions for the 757, but came up empty. Nothing matched that unit.

What are its features? Say compared to Boeing's own ACARS/AOC for datalink (via the standard CDUs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an American Airlines ACARS unit.

Comment: I suppose they beat Boeing to it then, thanks.